# continue a for loop outside of a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

so let's say I have something like this:

```
var x = 2;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if(someFunctionThatChecksX(x)) {
           continue;
         }
      }
}
```

I can't use continue because "jump target cannot cross function boundaries" and need a way around that to continue the for loop when that function that checks X results in true. Thanks so much for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the for loop to wait for the promise to resolve, put it inside of an async block. You could then use await to get the result of the promise, and continue based off that in the body of the for loop.

Altogether, it looks like this:

```
async function myFunction() {
    var x = 2;
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       let result = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
           resolve(someFunctionThatChecksX(x))
       }
       if(result) {
           continue;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that's helpful, but the promise is actually going in an array that's then has await Promise.all(thePromises), and there's a bunch of stuff under that check that I need to happen if someFunctionThatChecksX is false

Comment: If the for loop doesn't wait for the promise to resolve, it can't be affected by what happens inside the promise because there's no way to know when/if that stuff happens, and the loop's execution just continues immediately.

Comment: Technically you could make a mess with global variables and have the for loop do something when the promise does something, but that would be bad because there's no guarantee about when that happens.

Comment: Hearing your second comment there about the loop continuing immediately helped me see better logic to get what I needed done, thanks so much!